# How do I efficiently reorder bytes of a __m256i vector (convert int32_t to uint8_t)?

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I need to optimize the following compression operation (on a server with AVX2 instructions available):

take the exponents of an array of floats, shift and store to a uint8_t array

I have little experience and was suggested to start with https://github.com/feltor-dev/vcl library

now that I have

```
uint8_t* uin8_t_ptr = ...;
float* float_ptr = ...;
float* final_ptr = float_ptr + offset;

for (; float_ptr < final_ptr; float_ptr+=8) {
    Vec8f vec_f = Vec8f().load(float_ptr);
    Vec8i vec_i = fraction(vec_f) + 128; // range: 0~255
    ...
}
```

My question is how to efficiently store the vec_i results to the uint8_t array?

I couldn't find relevant functions in the vcl library and was trying to explore the intrinsic instructions since I could access the __m256i data.

My current understanding is to use something like _mm256_shuffle_epi8, but don't know the best way to do it efficiently.

I wonder if trying to fully utilize the bits and store 32 elements every time (using a loop with float_ptr+=32) would be the way to go.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Does your compiler effectively vectorize for you if you ask it nicely?  If so, I would start here as it will teach you all sorts of tricks and may even do the job good enough that you won't need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @michael-dorgan, I'm not sure how to proceed with this, though.
Can you maybe share some reference/tutorial? I'm using gcc 5.4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Probably your best bet for vectorization of this might be with `vpackssdw` / `vpackuswb`, and `vpermd` as a lane-crossing fixup after in-lane pack.**

- **`_mm256_srli_epi32`** to shift the exponent (and sign bit) to the bottom in each 32-bit element.  A logical shift leaves a non-negative result regardless of the sign bit.
- Then pack pairs of vectors down to 16-bit with **`_mm256_packs_epi32`** (signed input, signed saturation of output).
- Then **mask off the sign bit**, leaving an 8-bit exponent.  We wait until now so we can do 16x `uint16_t` elements per instruction instead of 8x `uint32_t`.  Now you have 16-bit elements holding values that fit in `uint8_t` without overflowing.
- Then pack pairs of vectors down to 8-bit with **`_mm256_packus_epi16`** (signed input, *unsigned* saturation of output).  This actually matters, `packs` would clip some valid values because your data uses the full range of `uint8_t`.
- **VPERMD** to shuffle the eight 32-bit chunks of that vector that came from each lane of 4x 256-bit input vectors.  Exactly the same `__m256i lanefix = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(abcd, _mm256_setr_epi32(0,4, 1,5, 2,6, 3,7));` shuffle as in [How to convert 32-bit float to 8-bit signed char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778721/how-to-convert-32-bit-float-to-8-bit-signed-char/51779212#51779212), which does the same pack after using FP->int conversion instead of right-shift to grab the exponent field.

---

Per result vector, you have 4x load+shift (`vpsrld ymm,[mem]` hopefully), 2x `vpackssdw` shuffles, 2x `vpand` mask, 1x `vpackuswb`, and 1x `vpermd`.  That's 4 shuffles, so the best we can hope for on Intel HSW/SKL is 1 result vector per 4 clocks.  (Ryzen has better shuffle throughput, except for `vpermd` which is expensive.)

But that should be achievable, so 32 bytes of input / 8 bytes of output per clock on average.

The 10 total vector ALU uops (including the micro-fused load+ALU), and the 1 store should be able to execute in that time.  We have room for 16 total uops including loop overhead before the front-end becomes a worse bottleneck than shuffles.

update: oops, **I forgot to count unbiasing the exponent; that will take an extra `add`.  But you can do that after packing down to 8-bit.**  (And optimize it to an XOR).  I don't think we can optimize it away or into something else, like into masking away the sign bit.

With AVX512BW, you could do a byte-granularity `vpaddb` to unbias, with zero-masking to zero the high byte of each pair.  That would fold the unbiasing into the 16-bit masking.

---

**AVX512F also has [`vpmovdb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb) 32->8 bit truncation** (without saturation), but only for single inputs.  So you'd get one 64-bit or 128-bit result from one input 256 or 512-bit vector, with 1 shuffle + 1 add per input instead of 2+1 shuffles + 2 zero-masked `vpaddb` per input vector.  (Both need the right shift per input vector to align the 8-bit exponent field with a byte boundary at the bottom of a dword)

With **AVX512VBMI, [`vpermt2b`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermt2b)** would let us grab bytes from 2 input vectors.  But it costs 2 uops on CannonLake, so only useful on hypothetical future CPUs if it gets cheaper.  They can be the top byte of a dword, so we could start with `vpaddd` a vector to itself to left-shift by 1.  But we're probably best with a left-shift because the EVEX encoding of [`vpslld`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psllw:pslld:psllq) or `vpsrld` *can* take the data from memory with an immediate shift count, unlike the VEX encoding.  So hopefully we get a single micro-fused load+shift uop to save front-end bandwidth.

---

**The other option is to shift + blend, resulting in byte-interleaved results that are more expensive to fix up, unless you don't mind that order.**

And byte-granularity blending (without AVX512BW) requires `vpblendvb` which is 2 uops.  (And on Haswell only runs on port 5, so potentially a huge bottleneck.  On SKL it's 2 uops for any vector ALU port.)

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I'll need some digestion since I just discovered this new world of intrinsic instructions.