# _mm256_packs_epi32, except pack sequentially

Tags: x86-64, simd, avx2

One can use _mm256_packs_epi32. as follows:  `__m256i e = _mm256_packs_epi32 ( ai, bi);`

In the debugger, I see the value of ai: `m256i_i32 = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}`. I also see the value of bi: `m256i_i32 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}`. The packing gave me e: `m256i_i16 = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}`. The packing is interleaved. So we have in e first four numbers in ai, first four numbers in bi, last four numbers in ai, last four numbers in bi in that order.

I am wondering if there is an instruction that just packs ai and bi side by side without the interleaving.

vpermq after packing would work, but I'm wondering if there's a single instruction to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sequential-across-lanes pack until AVX-512, unfortunately.  (And even then only for 1 register, or not with saturation.)

The in-lane behaviour of shuffles like `vpacksswd` and `vpalignr` is one of the major warts of AVX2 that make the 256-bit versions of those shuffles less useful than their `__m128i` versions.  But on Intel, and Zen2 CPUs, it is often still best to use `__m256i` vectors with a `vpermq` at the end, if you need the elements in a specific order.   (Or `vpermd` with a vector constant after 2 levels of packing: [How do I efficiently reorder bytes of a __m256i vector (convert int32_t to uint8_t)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839379/how-do-i-efficiently-reorder-bytes-of-a-m256i-vector-convert-int32-t-to-uint8))

---

If your 32-bit elements came from unpacking narrower elements, and you don't care about order of the wider elements, **you can widen with in-lane unpacks, which sets you up to pack back into the original order.**

This is cheap for zero-extending unpacks: `_mm256_unpacklo/hi_epi16` (with `_mm256_setzero_si256()`).   That's as cheap as `vpmovzxwd` (`_mm256_cvtepu16_epi32`), and is actually better because you can do 256-bit loads of your source data and unpack two ways, instead of narrow loads to feed `vpmovzx...` which only works on data at the bottom of an input register.  (And memory-source `vpmovzx... ymm, [mem]` can't micro-fuse the load with a YMM destination, only for the 128-bit XMM version, on Intel CPUs, so the front-end cost is the same as separate load and shuffle instructions.)

But that trick doesn't work work quite as nicely for data you need to sign-extend.  `vpcmpgtw` to get high halves for `vpunpckl/hwd` does work, but `vpermq` when re-packing is about as good, just different execution-port pressure.  So `vpmovsxwd` is simpler there.

---

**Slicing up your data into odd/even instead of low/high can also work,** e.g. to get 16 bit elements zero-extended into 32-bit elements:

```
   auto  veven  = _mm256_and_si256(v, _mm256_set1_epi32(0x0000FFFF));
   auto  vodd   = _mm256_srli_epi32(v, 16);
```

After processing, one can recombine with a shift and `vpblendw`. (1 uop for port 5 on Intel Skylake / Ice Lake).  Or for bytes, `vpblendvb` with a control vector, but that costs 2 uops on Intel CPUs (but for any port), vs. only 1 uop on Zen2.  (Those uop counts aren't including the `vpslld ymm, ymm, 16` shift to line up the odd elements back with their starting points.)

---

**Even with AVX-512, the situation isn't perfect.**  You still can use a single shuffle uop to combine 2 vectors to one of the same width.

There's very nice single-vector narrowing with truncation, or signed or unsigned saturation, for any pair of element sizes like an inverse of `vpmovzx` / `sx`.  e.g. [qword to byte `vpmov[su]qb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovqb:vpmovsqb:vpmovusqb), with an optional memory destination.

(Fun fact: `vpmovdm [rdi]{k1}, zmm0` was the only way Xeon Phi (lacking both AVX-512BW and AVX-512VL) could do byte-masked stores to memory; that might be why these exist in memory-destination form.  On mainstream Intel like Skylake-X / Ice Lake, the memory destination versions are no cheaper than separate pack into register then store.  https://uops.info/)

AVX-512 also has nice 2-input shuffles with a control vector, so for dword-to-word truncation you could use [`vpermt2w zmm1, zmm2, zmm3`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermt2w:vpermt2d:vpermt2q:vpermt2ps:vpermt2pd).  But that needs a shuffle control vector, and `vpermt2w` is 3 uops on SKX and IceLake.  (`t2d` and `t2q` are 1 uop).  `vpermt2b` is only available in AVX-512VBMI (Ice Lake), and is also 3 uops there.

(Unlike `vpermb` which is 1 uop on Ice Lake, and AVX-512BW `vpermw` which is [still 2 uops on Ice Lake](https://uops.info/html-tp/ICL/VPERMW_YMM_YMM_YMM-Measurements.html).  So they didn't reduce the front-end cost of the backwards-compatible instruction, but ICL can run 1 of its 2 uops on port 0 or 1, instead of both on the shuffle unit on port 5.  Perhaps ICL has one uop preprocess the shuffle control into a vpermb control or something, which would also explain the improved latency: 3 cycles for data->data, 4 cycles for control->data.  vs. 6 cycles on SKX for the 2p5 uops, apparently a serial dependency starting with both the control and data vectors.)