# how to store low 8 bits in every 32 bits data lane avx512?

Tags: c, avx512

how to store low 8 bits in every 32 bits data lane, for example, a zmm register stores 16 32-bit integer, I only need to store low 8 bits data to memory which is a int8_t array?

Comment: Which language do you use? C? X86_64 Assembly? C++?

Comment: C intrinsic@digito_evo

Comment: So add the C tag to your question. More people will see it.

Answer (score 2):

There's an instruction for that, `vpmovdb` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb).  But unfortunately Intel CPUs run it as 2 uops, both for port 5.  (Or 3 total with a memory destination; https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/).  C intrinsics

```
VPMOVDB __m128i _mm512_cvtepi32_epi8( __m512i a);
VPMOVDB __m128i _mm512_mask_cvtepi32_epi8(__m128i s, __mmask16 k, __m512i a);
VPMOVDB __m128i _mm512_maskz_cvtepi32_epi8( __mmask16 k, __m512i a);
VPMOVDB void _mm512_mask_cvtepi32_storeu_epi8(void * d, __mmask16 k, __m512i a);
```

Fun fact: it allows a memory *destination* and requires only AVX512F, not AVX512BW, so it's how KNL Xeon Phi could do byte-granularity masked stores.  There are signed and unsigned saturating forms, but you want the truncating form.

Truncation and lane-crossing packing are both new in AVX-512; in AVX2 you'd typically have to use 2x `vpackssdw` to feed `vpackuswb` and a `vpermq` fixup, also requiring masking the 32-bit data to be in the 0..255 unsigned range before packing, which would cost an extra `vpand` per *input* vector.

- [How do I efficiently reorder bytes of a __m256i vector (convert int32_t to uint8_t)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839379/how-do-i-efficiently-reorder-bytes-of-a-m256i-vector-convert-int32-t-to-uint8)
- [How to convert 32-bit float to 8-bit signed char? (4:1 packing of int32 to int8 __m256i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778721/how-to-convert-32-bit-float-to-8-bit-signed-char-41-packing-of-int32-to-int8)

---

#### With multiple vectors

If you have multiple vectors of data, it could be worthwhile to use AVX-512VBMI (Ice Lake / Zen 4) `vpermt2b` to grab bytes from two vectors.  That runs as 3 uops (2p5 + p015) on Intel CPUs that support it, so it's 2 cycles per 256-bit vector instead of 2 per 128-bit vector.

It's 1 uop on Zen 4, same as `vpmovdb`, so `vpermt2b` is ideal there, allowing one 256-bit store per clock, twice as fast as Intel and with fewer front-end uops.

`vpack...` in-lane pack instructions are single uop on Intel and do 2:1 packing of 2 registers into one of the same width.  With a `vpermt2d` shuffle at the end, this could come out ahead for multiple vectors.

So given 4 ZMM registers, 4x `vpmovdb` would take 8 cycles of throughput on Intel.  4x `vpand` + 2x `vpackssdw` + 1x `vpackuswb` + `vpermq` will generate one ZMM ready to store per 4 clock cycles on Skylake/Cascade Lake or later.

(`vpermt2w` is available on Skylake-avx512 so would be usable instead of `vpackuswb` + `vpermq`, but is 3 uops there and on later Intel, unfortunately.)

Another idea with AVX2 instructions: *[how to convert uint32 to uint8 using simd but not avx512?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774643/how-to-convert-uint32-to-uint8-using-simd-but-not-avx512)* - `vpshufb` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`) to pack and zero, setting up for a 2-input shuffle with wider granularity.  But that requires one port5 uop per input vector.

---

Intel's C/C++ intrinsics guide (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) has a search which works on asm mnemonics; they're shorter to type and talk about.

Comment: ok I get it, thanks!